# UK visa after refused entry into India

Tags: visas, uk, denial-of-entry

I'm a Bangladesh citizen and in 2012 I was refused entry into India. They told me I must wait 60 days between visits. Oddly, a friend on the same flight with the exact same situation was let through. I returned 7 days later when this period lapsed without a problem. I have traveled to India 30 times since.

I am a frequent traveler to the UK for pleasure and currently possess a 10-year visitor visa which expires next month. I have traveled to the UK 9 times within that period for short visits. In the last 10 years, I have traveled to 15 countries including 6 trips to the USA and 2 to France.

I have a business in Bangladesh and I am confident of strong ties--I can't even consider moving to a different country.

The UK application asks me if I've ever been refused entry to any country. I have. I understand all applications are judged on their merits. However, I was told I no longer qualify for a NZ visa because the refusal means I have "serious character issues."

Bangladesh is considered a high-risk country for UK visas with a high refusal rate. How should I go about the application process? Is there anything I should pay special attention to? Does the entry refusal deplete my credibility?

Comment: The UK will see it as a "serious character issue" if you _don't tell the truth_ that you were once refused entry into a country. However, when you tell them you were once refused entry into India, you will also have plenty of space to inform them that you were allowed to enter India two months later, and 30 times since, and it would be extremly unlikely to be held against you.

Comment: "I was told I no longer qualify for a NZ visa" -- told by whom?

Comment: OP has not returned to clarify questions/clarifications in comments. Putting on hold.